# Plotting a multiplication of two sine waves in one screen

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot Voltage, Current and Power of a circuit in one plot in matlab. Here are the equations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure how to define the **phi** in matlab, is it just like `-3.14/4` or radians? if so can you tell me how to define it in a matlab script?

Here is the code I wrote for this task:

```
t = 0: 0.1:100;
pi = 3.14;
Vmax = 10;
Imax = 1;
f = 50;
phi_default = -pi/4;

Vsrc = Vmax * sin((2*pi*f) * t);
Isrc = Imax * sin((2*pi*f) * t + phi_default);

% Psrc = Vsrc * Isrc; %
% plot(t,Vsrc, t, Isrc, t, Psrc); %
% legend('V', 'I', 'P') ;

plot(t,Vsrc, t, Isrc);
legend('V', 'I');
```

The problem with the commented out lines is that as you may know the power is defined as `V * I` so when I want to do that I get this error: *Inner matrix dimensions must agree.* how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inner matrix dimensions must agree. how to fix this?

You want to do element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication.

```
Psrc = Vsrc .* Isrc;
          __^ here
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, can you please check the phi for phase different? because I can not see that phase difference in the resulted plot! so I guess I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Try it with different denominators (pi/4 like you have now, pi/2 and pi) - you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Psrc = Vsrc .* Isrc;
```

See MatLab help **Arithmetic Operators + - * / \ ^ '**.

Comment: Thanks, any comment on the phi (phase) declaration?